# missing some cases in createcontext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am kinda learning new features/approach of react library instead of pass props through components I used hooks and contextapi to pass data wıthout having props. So I'm stuck in some cases
for the default value if its empty in createContext gives me that errror; its give me TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWeather' of undefined 
if lets say value is 0 like createContext(0) it works but data not fetched. I am missing some small points but no idea where it is :) ?

I share the app through github repo can anyone check it out if u free and help me where ı am doing wrong ?

https://github.com/mrtyvz61/weather-finder-hooksContext

```
export const WeatherCtx = createContext();

const App = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    temprature: '',
    city: '',
    country: '',
    humidity: '',
    description: '',
    error: ''
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use context you need to render all the components that will use it inside the provider. In you code you have this:

```
<WeatherCtx.Provider
        value={{
          data: state,
          getWeather
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
</WeatherCtx.Provider>
...
```

And bellow it you have the `Weather` component that is the one using the context. In this case `Weather` (and all your components that will be accessing the context value) needs to be inside the provider:

```
<WeatherCtx.Provider ...>
    ...
    // <-- Weather needs to be here
</WeatherCtx.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that your API Key is in your code. This isn't a huge deal as it's just a small project and not likely for people to abuse your API key but it's bad practice. Look into using Enviroment Variables for storing your API key rather than hard coding it, here is a [link](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) for create-react-app, since that is what you're using.

Try passing just state and getWeather rather than doing `data: state, getWeather`.

A helpful tip is to use the ReactDevTools or even just `console.log(WeatherCtx)` within your form component to see what its values are.

> EDIT: I just noticed you dont have your components wrapped in the Context.Provider

You need to wrap your components trying to use Context within the Context.Provider like so

```
<Context.Provider>
//Components that need to use context
</Context.Provider>
```

Comment: I use new approach of react js which is useContext .